# Expectation value of position

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

Calculating the expectation value of position is taking the integral from 0 to $L$ of 
$\psi^*x\psi$, and $\langle x\rangle^2$ would be the result of that integral squared, by this logic, would it mean that  would be taking the integral from 0 to $L$ of $\psi^*x^2\psi$?

Comment: No, $<x>^2\ne <x^2>$ for the general case.

Answer (score 1):

In general, $\langle x\rangle^2$ and $\langle x^2\rangle$ are not the same quantity, as they are defined by:

$$\langle x\rangle^2 = \left(\int \psi^* x\psi dx\right)^2$$

and

$$\langle x^2\rangle = \int \psi^* x^2\psi dx$$

To show you that you should not in general expect these integrals to give the same result, consider the following example.  In the first case, you $x$ term in the integrand can have both positive and negative values whereas the second case can only have positive values since it is $x^2$.  This will result in different values for the integral.  Also, for a particle defined over a range symmetric about zero ($-L/2$ to $L/2$ for instance), certain states will have $\langle x\rangle = 0$, where as $\langle x^2\rangle \ne 0$.

You should note that the variance is defined by

$$\sigma^2 = \langle x^2\rangle - \langle x\rangle^2$$

So you should expect the results to be different for any statistical system.